# Change value of custom table data in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, kentico

I want to create a page where the user can modify my custom table data. I currently have a Custom table data source and a Basic repeater. The Transformation looks like this:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="200">
  <tr>
    <th>Node ID:</th>
    <td><%# Eval("helpful_nodeID") %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Culture Code:</th>
    <td><%# Eval("helpful_cultureCode") %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Not Helpful:</th>
    <td><%# Eval("helpful_no") %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Helpful:</th>
    <td><%# Eval("helpful_yes") %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button>Clear rating</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I would like my button to have the opposite effect of `Eval`, and force the value of 0 for `"helpful_no"` and `"helpful_yes"`.

Is there an easy way, such as `<% Set ("helpful_yes") = 0 %>` for example?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such easy thing as an Set method which would store the data. Neither in ASP.NET nor in Kentico. The best way is probably creating your own user control/ webpart to do it.

EDIT:
Following materials may be useful.

[How to create new webpart](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+new+web+parts)

Every installation of Kentico also contains API examples section. If you are on Kentico 8, just open application list, type API examples, open it. There under development section you'll find custom tables examples which shows how to do basic manipulation with custom table objects.

Comment: Thanks. Can you direct me to any resource which could help me doing that?

Comment: @Deinonychus I've added resources to the answer.